# i'm having in php & html

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting some value in database & after inserting when i check that value in database it's showing different values. why? please.. help me

my code is..

```
"INSERT INTO `tblRechargeReports` 
 (`rechargeOnNumber` , `rechargeOnOperator`, `rechargeAmount`, `rechargeOnCircle`, `rechargedOn`)
 VALUES('" . $array['rechargeOnNumber'] . "', '" . $array['rechargeOnOperator'] . "','" . $array['rechargeAmount'] . "', '" . $array['rechargeOnCircle'] . "', NOW() )";
```

when i checked after die() function then it's showing like.....

```
INSERT INTO `tblRechargeReports` (`rechargeOnNumber` , `rechargeOnOperator`, `rechargeAmount`, `rechargeOnCircle`, `rechargedOn`) 
VALUES('9002261639', '1','100', '2', NOW() )
```

Comment: what are u inserting and what gets inserted pls give sample cases

Comment: And what's table scturcture?

Comment: change rechargeOnNumber  to varchar

Comment: your query is perfect but what you used and where you used and show what values you show in database table of tblRechargeReports table?

Comment: i'm inserting rechargeOnNumber = 9002261639 but in database it shows 2147483647

Comment: yeah i commeted above change it to varchar

Comment: table structure is `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 `rechargeOnNumber` INT(20) NOT NULL,
 `rechargeOnOperator` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `rechargeAmount` INT(5) NOT NULL,
 `rechargeOnCircle`  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `rechargedOn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `rechargeData` TEXT(100) NULL,
 `rechargeStatus` ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
 `isDelete` ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `IDX_rechargeOnOperator` (`rechargeOnOperator`)

Comment: on rechargonnumber you have to take either bigint or varchar but you cant take INT for that big value

Answer (score 0):

Please take datatype for mobile number as `bigint` or `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below table strtucture:

```
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
rechargeOnNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
rechargeOnOperator VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
rechargeAmount INT(5) NOT NULL, 
rechargeOnCircle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
rechargedOn DATETIME NOT NULL, 
rechargeData TEXT(100) NULL, 
rechargeStatus ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y', 
isDelete ENUM('Y', 'N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N', 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
UNIQUE KEY IDX_rechargeOnOperator (rechargeOnOperator)
```